# AngularJS way of changing class name on ng-click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I know it is good practice to not use jQuery inside an AngularJS app, but struggling to work out the AngularJS way of doing this:

```
$scope.clickEvent = function(event) {
    if($(event.target).hasClass('icon-closed')) {
        $(event.target).removeClass('icon-closed')
        $(event.target).addClass('icon-opened')
    } else {
        $(event.target).removeClass('icon-opened')
        $(event.target).addClass('icon-closed')
    }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="component-title icon-closed" 
     ng-model="collapsed" 
     ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed;clickEvent($event)">{{component.name}}</div>
```

The `collapsed` code is showing/hiding panels, and the div is within an `ng-repeat` loop, so nothing to do with the `clickEvent` function.

I was hoping I could get the class names from the event object & alter them without using jQuery. Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ngClass` directive to achieve this.

```
<div class="component-title"
     ng-class="{'icon-closed':collapsed,'icon-opened':!collapsed}"
     ng-model="collapsed"
     ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">{{component.name}}</div>
```

More information on `ngClass` can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: Brilliant - works! I did play around with ng-class, but never thought to use my 'collapsed' var with it. Simple really! Thanks a lot :) Still getting my head around AngularJS when I've been using jQuery for so long...